# How to save rreturned values from function called in thread outside loop

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a simple function that takes as input two images and compares them. This function is applied separately for each subfolder in main folder, so I used Thread to reduce computational time.

The approach is as follows:

```
def compare__two_images(image1, image2):  
    return image1 address if images are similar

def process_folders(path_to_folder):
    print("Current Folder: " + path_to_folder)
    start_time = time.time()
    input_arr = glob.glob(folder+'/*')
    res = ([compare_images(input_arr[i], input_arr[i + 1]) for i in range(len(input_arr) - 1)])
    print("Folder completed with " + str(time.time() - start_time))
    return res

threads = []
for folder in folder_with_subfolders:
threads.append(Thread(target=process_folders, args=(folder,)))
threads[-1].start()

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

The question is, how can I store the values returned in process_folders function outside threading in common list? Currenly, all I could achive is to write values to txt file in function